# Framework for service with thread pools

Tags: java, multithreading, frameworks

I want to write a service, which works kinda similar way as web server does, just with multi-threading inside: on a request, there should be a child thread (let's call it "worker") created, which takes care of the request. The worker itself then would launch few other threads, where each thread does different kind of work. Threads should be taken from predefined pools for each kind of thread. The worker would wait then till all of threads are finished, take the results from each of them, pack them to the one "bucket" and return it back as result/response of the request.

Are there any good libraries or frameworks, that would fit for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at Java's executor framework. In my opinion, it provides enough functionality for most thread-pooling purposes. It's based around the `Executor` and `ExecutorService` interfaces:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: +1: The built in thread pool is usually the right answer I find. ;)

Comment: How do you then pack the results from each thread to one bucket and return it as a response. AFAIR, the Executor Service only helps with the pooling part, how about the collation of results from each thread part? I was thinking of the Java 7 fork-join addition, but outside Java 7, how can this be done?

Comment: If you have multiple workers that run in parallel and you want to start them all at the same time and wait for the results, use `ExecutorService.invokeAll()`. Otherwise, just use `ExecutorService.submit()` every time you need to "fork" a task and store the resulting `Future`s. Later, you can invoke `Future.get()` to wait for and retrieve results.